# RestKit and storing of data

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I have a navigation controller where i have the list of appointments in a table view. I have an add button on the right side corner for the navigation controller. When the user clicks the add button a view will appear with the textfields and buttons. The problem is when ever the user (of the app) adds his appointments and clicks the add button it has to hit the server and store that data. I want to do that using RestKit. Can anybody tell me how to hit the server and how i can store the data.

Comment: Can you give more information? Are you using Core Data to store on the  device? Have you tried adding RestKit into your project? Have you written any mappings? I don't have a feel for where in this process you are.

Comment: One of the things you should consider if you go with RestKit, is implementing an `RKManagedObjectCache`. It will help maintain current data in your local data store, and can reduce the necessity for hitting the network as often as you otherwise might need to.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Google can.

Here is the first result for the search 'restkit tutorial' :

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/

And, in case that one is a little out of date, here's the second result for the search 'restkit tutorial' :

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/advanced-restkit-development_iphone-sdk/

Comment: That tutorial is very old, so unless he uses an older release of RestKit it won't be of much use to him.

Comment: My point wasn't really to give a tutorial, more to say 'try google' ;)

Comment: Sorry, but the second link you added is also very out of date. My point being that in this case, google failed. The current documentation is available on github.

Answer (score 2):

The current documentation is only on github. Most other sources are outdated, thanks to RestKit's rapid development.

The [wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki) has a lot of good information, and you can find documentation that's always up-to-date in the [docs directory](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/tree/master/Docs).

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a detailled overview of RestKit with many piece of code and I think it can help you to understand how it works and how to get things done.

http://blog.octo.com/en/overview-of-restkit-a-core-data-enabled-ios-macosx-framework-for-restful-apps/

Comment: I tried the code in this tutorial (the one in the "A real life example with RKClient" section) but I cannot get it to work completely. The request works and I get the data but app crashes at the end with 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', indicating the reason as 'Attempted to decrement loading count below zero'. I posted my question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865471/getting-restkit-tutorial-code-to-work). Any ideas why?

Comment: I answered you. It looks like a configuration issue (ARC, Other Linker flags).