# Getting Restkit tutorial code to work

Tags: iphone, ios, json, restkit

I am relatively new to development on iOS and trying to get familiarized with RestKit, so bear with me if I am missing something obvious.

We are developing an iOS 5 application that will receive and map JSON to objects (ARC is enabled, if it matters). In search of a tutorial for Restkit, I came across [this one](http://blog.octo.com/en/overview-of-restkit-a-core-data-enabled-ios-macosx-framework-for-restful-apps). However, a simplified version of the sample code there (the one in the "A real life example with RKClient" section) fails with the following error:

```
2012-01-14 22:15:55.124 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] *** Assertion failure in -[RKRequestQueue removeRequest:decrementCounter:], /Users/m/Documents/devel/ios/RestKit/Code/Network/RKRequestQueue.m:350
2012-01-14 22:15:55.129 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to decrement loading count below zero'
```

To be exact, here's the code I have tried:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"some_url"];
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

    NSDictionary *queryParameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];
    NSString *getResourcePath = RKPathAppendQueryParams(@"some_url_segment", queryParameters);
    RKRequest *request = [client get:getResourcePath delegate:self];
    [request sendAsynchronously];
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response
{
    id jsonParser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    NSError *error = nil;
    id parsedResponse = [jsonParser objectFromString:[response bodyAsString] error:&error];
    if (error == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"GET returned with HTTP Code %d and parsedContent: %@", [response statusCode], parsedResponse);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failure of GET with error %@.", error);
}
```

Here's the trace output:

```
2012-01-14 22:15:54.746 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] I restkit:RKLog.m:30 RestKit initialized...
2012-01-14 22:15:54.765 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] D restkit.network:RKRequest.m:365 Sending asynchronous GET request to URL <url>.
2012-01-14 22:15:54.771 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:313 Prepared GET URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest url>'. HTTP Headers: {
    "Content-Length" = 0;
}. HTTP Body: .
2012-01-14 22:15:54.852 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:369 Network availability has been determined for reachability observer <RKReachabilityObserver: 0x15c920 host=<server ip> isReachabilityDetermined=YES isMonitoringLocalWiFi=448340 reachabilityFlags=-R ------d>
2012-01-14 22:15:54.857 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] D restkit.network:RKClient.m:388 Reachability to host '<server ip>' determined for client <RKClient: 0x158740>, unsuspending queue <RKRequestQueue: 0x15b260 name=(null) suspended=YES requestCount=1 loadingCount=0/5>
2012-01-14 22:15:55.037 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:189 NSHTTPURLResponse Status Code: 200
2012-01-14 22:15:55.044 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:190 Headers: {
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sat, 14 Jan 2012 20:16:21 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
}
2012-01-14 22:15:55.048 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] T restkit.network:RKResponse.m:195 Read response body: <json text here>
2012-01-14 22:15:55.059 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:565 Status Code: 200
2012-01-14 22:15:55.066 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] D restkit.network:RKRequest.m:566 Body: <json text here>
2012-01-14 22:15:55.106 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] GET returned with HTTP Code 200 and parsedContent: <json text here>
2012-01-14 22:15:55.124 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] *** Assertion failure in -[RKRequestQueue removeRequest:decrementCounter:], /Users/m/Documents/devel/ios/RestKit/Code/Network/RKRequestQueue.m:350
2012-01-14 22:15:55.129 Test_StaticLibInApp[789:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to decrement loading count below zero'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x33fac8bf 0x341fc1e5 0x33fac7b9 0x3595b3b3 0x1da7f 0x1e7a3 0x3598150f 0x33f78577 0x33f040cf 0x358f53fb 0x1818b 0x2064b 0x359b8c39 0x359106e9 0x359106b3 0x359105d5 0x31fbe8a5 0x31fb3545 0x31fb3243 0x31fb3179 0x33f80b03 0x33f802cf 0x33f7f075 0x33f024dd 0x33f023a5 0x30786fcd 0x37383743 0x2c81 0x2c18)
```

Is this error somehow related to the application being compiled with ARC? For Restkit installation, I got the files from the git master branch and followed the installation instructions, not changing any of its settings.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the line

**[request sendAsynchronously]**

is not needed.

**[client get:getResourcePath delegate:self]**

already sends the request, and decrements the request count.  you are getting

**reason: 'Attempted to decrement loading count below zero'**

because of this.

Answer (score 0):

RestKit should not be compiled with ARC enabled.
What I do is compile RestKit for Simulator and Device and then add the resulting .a and includes in my ARC enabled project.
Also, did you add -all_load -ObjC to Other Linker Flags?
Regards,

Comment: I did not compile RestKit with ARC, just the application. For Restkit installation, I got the files from the git master branch and followed the installation instructions [in this link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x), not changing any of the settings.

Comment: It seems the `[request sendAsynchronously]` line was not needed. Check the selected answer for details.

Comment: oops yes indeed, sorry for the mistake.